# Trying to get cookie with ngx-cookie but 'document is not defined' if I F5 the page

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, cookies

Something strange is going on. It seems maybe the document object does not exist. When I just save the code and click back to the browser it works fine. Why is the document going away when I press F5?

```
 let x = this.cookieService.get("UserID");
    console.log("x= " + x);
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is not defined
>   ReferenceError: document is not defined
>   at CookieService.get [as cookieString] (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10652:13)
>   at CookieService._cookieReader (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10751:40)
>   at CookieService.get (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10670:21)
>   at new HomeComponent (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16948:36)
>   at createClass (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21881:26)
>   at createDirectiveInstance (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21699:37)
>   at createViewNodes (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23127:49)
>   at createRootView (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23022:5)
>   at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23707:12)
>   at ComponentFactory_.module.exports.ComponentFactory_.create (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:20813:46)
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is not defined
>   ReferenceError: document is not defined
>   at CookieService.get [as cookieString] (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10652:13)
>   at CookieService._cookieReader (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10751:40)
>   at CookieService.get (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10670:21)
>   at new HomeComponent (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16948:36)
>   at createClass (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21881:26)
>   at createDirectiveInstance (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21699:37)
>   at createViewNodes (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23127:49)
>   at createRootView (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23022:5)
>   at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23707:12)
>   at ComponentFactory_.module.exports.ComponentFactory_.create (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:20813:46)
>   at resolvePromise (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:86165:31)
>   at resolvePromise (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:86136:17)
>   at C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:86213:17
>   at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85819:31)
>   at Object.onInvokeTask (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:14821:37)
>   at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85818:36)
>   at Zone.module.exports.Zone.runTask (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85586:47)
>   at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85979:35)
>   at 
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+d__7.MoveNext()

Stack Query Cookies Headers

> NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is not defined ReferenceError: document is not defined at CookieService.get [as cookieString] (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10652:13) at CookieService._cookieReader (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10751:40) at CookieService.get (C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10670:21) at new

Answer (score 1):

Document is not accessible on the server side. The cookie management must be browser side.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Angular is client side. How is different when I F5 ?

Comment: `(C:\Users\Matt_Herb\Downloads\IbewSurveyTemp\IbewSurveyTemp\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10652:13) at CookieService._cookieReader `
main-server.js is part of universal

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in app.server.module.ts file

```
  providers: [
    { provide: CookieService, useClass: CookieBackendService },
  ]
```